# Open/Resize window without a link

Tags: javascript

Guess I am trying to do things that are not usually done in javascript as I am not having much luck googling it.

I have a drop down menu with several choices.

When the user chooses something from the drop down menu it is submitted and the page reloads. I then have an if statement that will do different things depending on what was chosen from the drop down menu.

So if the user chooses PDF from the drop down, I want to be able to load a new window automatically without having to click a link when the script encounters it.

This works, but I want it to do the same thing without the link.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<a class='link' href="javascript: void(0)" 

onclick="window.open('print-pdf.php?inv=', 'print', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">Print</a>
```

Comment: Please show the dropdown menu option you'd like to use this with. :)

Comment: You guys are killing me, this is a simple as you get drop down menu. Anyone you can come up with will do.

Comment: <form action="home.php" method="post" name="perform">
   <select name="action" type='dropdown' style="font-size: 8pt; width: 70px">
   <option value='editinvoice.php'>Edit Cust</option>
   <option value='view.php'>Add Notes</option>
   <option value='print'>Print</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
   </form>

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you would like code for an actual drop down menu?

Comment: Thank you, I will update my answer below.

Comment: No, I need code to put in my PHP if statement.

Comment: if(dropdown choice = pdf) { open new window }

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as far as I can tell, you'd like to use this script when the user clicks an option from the Drop Down menu, right?

So, what you do is, on your dropdown menu option code, do this:

```
onclick="window.open('hi.html', 'print', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;"
```

If your menu options are created using `<li>` tags, then it would look like this:

```
<li onclick="window.open('hi.html', 'print', 

'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">Launch PDF</li>
```

Hope this helps.

Update:

This may work, however my server's stuffed so I can't test PHP right now:

```
if($_REQUEST["inv"]=="print")
{
   header("Location: window.open('print-pdf.php?inv=', 'print','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;");
}
```

Comment: Your last option is more of what I need, but it does not work. It just display every thing after Location:

Comment: Okay, we're getting somewhere atleast. I'll tweak it a little and um post more code.

Comment: I was getting somewhere, but it opens the same window I am on, even though it is specified what to open.

Comment: if($_POST['action'] == "print") {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.open("http://md.ldn/print-pdf.php?inv=<? echo $r['record_number']; ?>", 'print','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes')</script>
  <?
 }

Comment: From the code you've posted, I can't see anywhere where you've defined 'action'. Did you remember to add 'action' to the corresponding name attribute on the form?

Comment: Check the code above, I did have the action there - <form action="home.php" method="post" name="perform">